# Direct keyboard shortcut for viewing Class Member documentation in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

In Xcode (v.6), I'm aware of the <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Left-Click</kbd> option to open quick help, then I can click the "Class Reference" section to get to Apple's official documentation directly.

**My question**: Is there an easy way to do the same thing via the keyboard?

In general I try to avoid using the mouse where possible for efficiency - I've scoured the key bindings section & SO but haven't come up with anything obvious. Am I missing something relatively simple, or would I have to perform some mouse-click hackery?

I'm also aware of the "Search documentation" & "Open Quick Help" shortcuts, but neither of these seems to provide me with a keyboard-accessible way to get to the Class Reference directly. I can't tab through the pop-up from Quick-Help, & retyping what I'm looking for in the Search is slow (slower than mouse-clicks).

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since you asked, but if anyone finds this:

The keyboard shortcut is: **ctrl + cmd + question mark.**

**Note**
In some keyboards you may need to press shift to get the question mark.

Comment: No - this is the "Open Quick Help" shortcut, not the full Class Reference. Is there a way I can open the actual documentation reference from the pop-up via keyboard? (As far as I can tell, the answer is no)

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 7.3, the command is called `Search Documentation for Selected Text`, which is set to `control + option + command + /` by default.